# is there a method to eliminate this vertical white line on the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i can't solve this css problem, i made my website in react but in the mobile version i found this problem that when i zoom out the screen you see this vertical white line on the right.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCoJQ.png)

I tried to look everywhere for a solution and most people said to put margin: 0, padding: 0, but nothing.

in my app.css:

```
 *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  }
```

There's a way? thanks!

Comment: attach your whole codebase

Answer (score 0):

Set the style on `body` specifically

```
body {
   margin: 0,
   padding: 0,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

that's my main:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/pages/HomePage/Home';
import Services from './components/pages/Services/Services';
import Products from './components/pages/Products/Products';
import Contattaci from './components/pages/Contattaci/Contattaci';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/pages/Footer.js/Footer';
import Terms from './components/Terms';
import CookieConsent, { Cookies } from "react-cookie-consent";

function App() {
return (
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
    <Route path='/services' component={Services} />
    <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
    <Route path='/contattaci' component={Contattaci} />
    <Route path='/terms' component={Terms} />
    <div></div>
  </Switch>
  <CookieConsent>Questo sito web usa i cookie per migliorare l'esperienza dell'utente. 
  </CookieConsent>
  <Footer />
</Router>
 );
 }
 export default App;
```

then i've created a app.css

```
 *{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   }
```

the rest are other files that connect to main

Comment: These should be added as part of your original question, not as an answer.

Comment: it was to answer William

Comment: Answers are meant to answer the main question, not other answers :)